# Using DispatchGroup to populate object's array not working properly

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, object, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to populate my object's array with more objects. I'd been using dispatch group without issues but now that I have to use an array, it's not working. I get the array empty like if it was never populated. I'm not that familiar with GCD and I would like a tip about what I'm doing wrong.

The first time I use GCD with the customer, it works but when I use it again for all the items, it doesn't. I somehow know that it's not waiting for all the items to be processed and it's sending the empty array initialized since the beginning.

Hope someone could help me with this. Cheers!

```
static func loadAll(_ completion: @escaping ([Ticket1]?) -> Void) -> UInt {
    return FirebaseService.instance.readAll(from: .tickets, returning: Ticket1.self, { (tickets) in
        if tickets != nil {
            var result = [Ticket1]()
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            for var ticket in tickets! {
                dispatchGroup.enter()
                Customer.loadSingleObject(withID: ticket.customerID, { (customer) in
                    if customer != nil {
                        ticket.customer = customer

                        for itemID in ticket.itemsID {
                            dispatchGroup.enter()
                            Item.loadSingleObject(withID: itemID, { (item) in
                                if item != nil {
                                    ticket.items?.append(item!)
                                } else {
                                    completion(nil)
                                }
                                dispatchGroup.leave()
                            })
                        }
                        result.append(ticket)
                    } else {
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
            }

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                result = result.sorted(by: { $0.createdAt > $1.createdAt })
                completion(result)
            })
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Copy/paste code, don't post a screenshot. You need to use a second dispatche group for `loadSingleObject()` at least.

Comment: Thanks! It worked as expected